# Type Error: type is not callable msg.sender()

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I copied and pasted the OpenZepplin Erc-20 contract but I am getting a type error on `msg.sender()` inside the transfer function. Not even sure what this is or why it's happening here's the code.

This is a cut-down version with just the functions that have errors.

```js
contract Coin {

mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    event Transfer(string from, string to, uint256 amount);
    event Approval(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount);

    /**
     * @dev Sets the values for {name} and {symbol}.
     *
     * The default value of {decimals} is 18. To select a different value for
     * {decimals} you should overload it.
     *
     * All two of these values are immutable: they can only be set once during
     * construction.
     */
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }

        /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transfer}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - the caller must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = msg.sender();
        _transfer(owner, to, amount);
        return true;
    }

    
    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` of tokens from `sender` to `recipient`.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to {transfer}, and can be used to
     * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `from` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `from` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount;
        }
        _balances[to] += amount;

        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to invoke `msg.sender` as if it was a function. It's not.
You are using it like:

```js
address owner = msg.sender(); // No need to put parenthesis on the sender
```

You should use it like:

```js
address owner = msg.sender;
```